# In MySQL, how to show count(*) as 0 instead of not showing the row at all?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So, a breakdown of the statement below, trying to find **total employees** that have **skill named**: p1, p2 and have **certified** > 10.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(empNumber) 
FROM SKILL 
WHERE (certified > 10) AND name IN ('p1', 'p2') 
GROUP BY name;
```

In the database:
P1 has 2 employees and P2 has 0 employees

But, what is showing is

```
name | count(empNumber)
P1   |       2
P2   |       0   <= this row doesn't show but would like if it does
```

Just by using select statement and no joins. Thanks

Comment: Hi Caramelia, maybe you can provide some examples of dummy data that you're analyzing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` logic into the count:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN certified > 10 THEN empNumber END)
FROM SKILL 
WHERE name IN ('p1', 'p2') 
GROUP BY name;
```

The problem with doing the check on `certified` in the `WHERE` clause is that it filters off non matching records *before* they can be tallied when the `GROUP BY` happens.  My version above aggregates over all the records, and then uses conditional aggregation to get the matching count.

You could also use `SUM` here:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN certified > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM SKILL
...
```

Comment: Somehow, yours doesn't work but this does CASE WHEN certified > 10 THEN empNumber END, even this CASE WHEN certified > 10 THEN 0 END. Could you help explain the logic. Tbh, the logic you provided made sense to me but it just didn't come out the same way

Comment: @CarameliaBachmann You're right, there should be no `ELSE` condition (or it should be `ELSE NULL`).  The issue here is that `COUNT` counts every non `NULL` column value as 1, and null as zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
select name, count(certified)
from skill
where name in ('p1','p2')
      and certified > 10
group by name
union
select b.name, 0 
from
(
  select name, count(certified)
  from skill
  where name in ('p1','p2')
       and certified <=10
  group by name
) b;
```

Illustration:

```
select * from skill;
+-----------+------+-----------+
| empNumber | name | certified |
+-----------+------+-----------+
|       100 | p1   |        11 |
|       101 | p1   |        12 |
|       102 | p2   |         0 |
|       103 | p2   |         5 |
+-----------+------+-----------+


-- run the query
+------+------------------+
| name | count(certified) |
+------+------------------+
| p1   |                2 |
| p2   |                0 |
+------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a convenient shorthand.  Based on your desired results, you can express this as:

```
SELECT name, SUM(certified > 10) 
FROM SKILL 
WHERE name IN ('p1', 'p2') 
GROUP BY name;
```

This is counting skills.  To count employees, I think you need:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN certified > 10 THEN empnumber END) 
FROM SKILL 
WHERE name IN ('p1', 'p2') 
GROUP BY name;
```

If the names don't both exist in `SKILL` and you want to still see them in the result set, you need a `LEFT JOIN` (or union of some sort):

```
SELECT n.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.empnumber)  
FROM (SELECT 'p1' as name UNION ALL SELECT 'p2' as name
     ) n LEFT JOIN
     SKILL s
     ON n.name = s.name AND s.certified > 10
GROUP BY n.name;
```

Note some changes to this query:

- I can move the filtering condition to the `ON` because the `LEFT JOIN` will keep both names.
- I have introduced table aliases.
- All column references are qualified, so it is clear what tables they come from.

Finally, the question is:

> trying to find total employees that have skill named: p1, p2 and have certified > 10

This is a number, not a row for each employee.  I believe this answers the question:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT empnumber 
      FROM SKILL 
      HAVING SUM( name = 'p1' ) > 0 AND
             SUM( name = 'p2' ) > 0 AND
             SUM( certified > 10 ) > 0
      GROUP BY empnumber
     ) es;
```

The subquery finds all employees that have all three conditions.  The `SUM()` is the number of skills per employee that match a given condition.  The `> 0` says that the particular condition is matched.

Answer (score -2):

maybe this way ?

```
SELECT name, COUNT(empNumber) as empNum
FROM SKILL 
WHERE (certified > 10) AND name IN ('p1', 'p2') 
GROUP BY name
HAVING empNum > 0
```

Have a nice day :)

Comment: This will only further filter the result set. The question is specfically asking how to _add_ the missing row, not remove rows